# How to get the JOOQ query text using AspectJ without changing the query method itself?

Tags: java, aspectj, jooq

There is a project using JOOQ.
Example of the method:

```
public List<A> getA(List<String> C) {
    return context
            .select(...)
            .from(...)
            .join(...).on(...)
            .where(...)
            .fetch().map(...);
}
```

You need to use AspectJ to get the request text.

Everything is OK with HPQL and JDBC, according to the first - we work with the annotation, according to the second - we intercept the parameter with the query from the public JDBC class.

Example point for JDBC:

```
@Pointcut("target(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate) && " +
        "args(String, ..) && (call(* query(..)) || call(* update(..)) || call(* batchUpdate(..)))")
public void executeMetricsRepository() { }
```

But what can you do here? It is with the application of the aspect, because rewriting each request is not considered.

There are two parts here - fetch() and map(). But interested in - fetch.

fetch ---> interface org.jooq.ResultQuery

Inherited classes:

AbstractResultQuery and SelectImpl. But it is package-private.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Then, please provide one, ideally on GitHub. The information given here does not make the problem reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

#### Alternative approach without AspectJ

I'm not sure if you *have to* use this annotation based approach, but it is very easy to extract the SQL query for *every* jOOQ query in your application by adding an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-execute-listeners/) to your jOOQ `Configuration`, e.g.

```java
configuration.set(ExecuteListener.onRenderEnd(ctx -> {

    // Or, do whatever.
    System.out.println(ctx.sql());
}));
```

#### Possibility to use AspectJ

The jOOQ `Query` type has a [`Query.getSQL()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/AttachableQueryPart.html#getSQL()) method which can be used to extract the generated SQL for any `Query`. That's a bit less efficient than the above approach, because it will re-generate the SQL string a second time, but that might be irrelevant to your application?

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful for me in debugging a query which returned 21 million records on my local machine... :) Enabling `DEBUG` logging for `org.jooq` wasn't enough, but setting up an `onRenderEnd()` listener like this helped. Big thanks!

Comment: @PerLundberg: Why wasn't enabling `DEBUG` logging not enough (assuming you turned on the `ExecuteListener`)?

Comment: Precisely because I didn't turn on the `ExecuteListener`, most likely. ;) (TBH, I don't even remember how to do it, I would have to read the Fine manual. I just enabled `debug` logging, presuming out would be enough, which it wasn't and then googled which led me here... :P)

Comment: @PerLundberg: It's enabled by default. [You probably turned it off with `Settings.executeLogging`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-execute-logging/)

Comment: @PerLundberg: You could ask a new question about this: *"Why doesn't jOOQ log anything despite enabling `DEBUG` logging"*, and I'll repeat this answer. You might find your own Q&A useful again in the future :)

Comment: Alright, here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564333/jooq-doesnt-log-the-sql-queries-it-executes-despite-enabling-debug-logging. I checked in our application and we don't seem to be calling the `Settings.executeLogging()` method AFAICT. I guess I'll have to re-test and see how it behaves when `org.jooq` DEBUG logging is enabled...